# Not able to set textview drawable dynamically

Tags: android, textview

Im trying to create a textview dynamically . I want to set the drawable to textview`

```
TextView tab = new TextView(getContext());
        tab.setText(title);
        tab.setSingleLine();
        tab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        int padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.offset);
        tab.setPadding(0,0,padding,0);
        if(typeface!= null){
            tab.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
        tab.setCompoundDrawables(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp),null,null,null);
```

`
But I'm not able to achieve it. Can anyone of you help me out.

Comment: use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this use **[setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))**
>

```
void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (Drawable left, 
                Drawable top, 
                Drawable right, 
                Drawable bottom)
```

> Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text. Use null if you do not want a Drawable there. The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.
>
> Calling this method will overwrite any Drawables previously set using setCompoundDrawablesRelative(Drawable, Drawable, Drawable, Drawable) or related methods.

**sample code**

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTxtView);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

use **[setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))**

> Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the
>   right of, and below the text. Use null if you do not want a Drawable
>   there. The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp),null,null,null);
```

**OR**

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp),0,0,0);
```

Comment: @SaudaSadaf Glad to hear .Move ahead